# Parsing a string intelligently to construct complex api calls

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, nlp, text-parsing

I've done a few hours of research but I've yet to find the golden answer.  This is one of those research topics I find difficult to explain to Google search.

Anyway, my goal is to take a string like below,

Step 1: User searches for, "3 bedroom apartment $2600 San Francisco".

---

Step 2: ?????? Magic happens in this layer ???????

---

Step 3: Intelligent api search string is constructed:

http://api.service.com/?city=San%20Francisco&heading="3 bedroom apartment"|"three bedroom apartment"|"3 bedroom apt"|"three bedroom apt"&min_price=2200&max_price=2800

The magic is Step 2 should be able to handle:

- mis-spellnigs
- Correctly predicts city
- Understands what a number means (if it is currency a.k.a "$3" or "3 dollars" or a value for something).
- Throws out common articles like "and", "the", etc.

Preferably, the solution uses PHP or Javascript asynchronous call to a third-party service I could use to perform the database algorithms and magic (Google??).  I'm open to building something with some open-source code that uses my own database too if needed.

Thanks guys for the insight!

Comment: i would keep everything semi-separated and have RegExps that can sniff out whole chunks of meaningful data. you should also have a cleanup first-pass that homogenizes whitespace, lowercase everything, changes "three"" into "3", and so on, to reduce the later "what-if" combinations. concentrated in a specific domain like apt hunting, one can make a reasonably smart interface in an afternoon or two. make whatever you build flexible enough to upgrade and refine as it develops.

Comment: You should leave that to a full text serach engine, like the one embedded on your db server, or something dedicated like Apache Solr.

Comment: bfavaretto can you link me to someone talking about this solution in-depth? Also, for my future research is it fair to say that what I'm trying to do here is called "Full Text Search".. I guess it would help to know how to describe what this is called that I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check [Wit](https://wit.ai), it does exactly what you need.
[image]

Comment: Oh man!  You sir could be my knight in shining armor! :)  I've signed up and am waiting to hear back from the Wit team for access.  TY!

Comment: Looks cool, though classic sketchy Facebook behavior: "You grant us a non-exclusive, transferable, sublicensable, royalty-free, worldwide license to host, use, distribute, modify, run, copy, store, display, translate, analyze, and create derivative works from Your Content, including any intellectual property rights contained therein, for any business purpose in connection with operating, providing or improving the Services." https://wit.ai/terms#3